# How can I remove the horizontal line that is added when printing huxtable in callout-block in Quarto v1.3?

Tags: r, quarto

This is a follow-up question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939801/is-there-a-way-to-override-bootstrap-styling-for-tables-in-quarto-v1-3), where I asked how to suppress bootstrap-layouting of tables in quarto v1.3. The solution was to add `#| output: asis` to the chunk-options and then add `|> print_html()` to the end of the code.
This works perfectly for normal use. However, when used in a callout-block, printing the table as HTML seems to disable the callout-block.
I found a workaround for this, which is to leave out the `|> print_html()`, like so:

````
---
title: Table style
format: html
---

::: {.callout-important}

Some text about the table

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| output: asis

library(huxtable)

t1 <-  matrix(c("",            "",   "Success", "",     "", 
                "",            "",   "no",      "yes",  "", 
                "Medication",  "A",  4,         2,      6,
                "",            "B",  2,         5,      7,
                "",            "",   6,         7,      13),
              nrow = 5, byrow = T)

huxtable::as_hux(t1) |> 
  set_bottom_border(row = c(2,4), col = 2:5) |>
  set_bottom_border(row = c(1,5), col = c(3,4)) |>
  
  set_right_border(row = 2:5, col = c(2,4)) |> 
  set_right_border(row = c(3,4), col = c(1,5)) |> 
  
  set_bold(row = 1, col = 3) |> 
  set_bold(row = 3, col = 1) |> 
  
  set_col_width(col = everywhere, 0.2)
```
:::
````

Again, this works fine, but it generates a grey line above the table, which I'd rather not have:
[image]
I found, that this is caused by the last code-line `set_col_width()`, but I absolutely need to set the col-width because the table looks ridiculous without.

Any ideas on how I could get rid of that grey horizontal line?

Comment: Using your code I do not get a grey line with quarto  Version: 0.9.512.

Comment: @TarJae are you using Quarto v1.3 too?

Comment: I checked my quarto version via `quarto check` in the Terminal and I got  `Version: 0.9.512` R version `Version: 4.2.2`

Comment: I can reproduce with quarto `1.3.271`

Comment: Yeah I had no problem with earlier versions, it is only since I upgraded to v1.3 that I encounter problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know the cause of this grey line, you can remove it with some CSS:

````
---
title: Table style
format: html
---

```{css}
#| echo: false
.huxtable {
    border-top: hidden;
}
```

::: {.callout-important}

Some text about the table

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| output: asis

library(huxtable)

t1 <-  matrix(c("",            "",   "Success", "",     "", 
                "",            "",   "no",      "yes",  "", 
                "Medication",  "A",  4,         2,      6,
                "",            "B",  2,         5,      7,
                "",            "",   6,         7,      13),
              nrow = 5, byrow = T)

huxtable::as_hux(t1) |> 
  set_bottom_border(row = c(2,4), col = 2:5) |>
  set_bottom_border(row = c(1,5), col = c(3,4)) |>
  
  set_right_border(row = 2:5, col = c(2,4)) |> 
  set_right_border(row = c(3,4), col = c(1,5)) |> 
  
  set_bold(row = 1, col = 3) |> 
  set_bold(row = 3, col = 1) |> 
  
  set_col_width(col = everywhere, 0.2)
```
:::
````

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that worked! I added the css-code to my `styles.css`-file so I don't have to repeat it for all 30 files. Thanks a lot!